# Error 500 Internal in [slug] from +page.server.js in Sveltekit

Tags: javascript, svelte, blogs, sveltekit, contentful

I have a blog website and I fetch the data from `contentfu.js` and everything is okay in `localhost`

The problem is when I reload a post page it shows the content when I click on the link in the deployed website.

But when I refresh the page or enter the slug URL it shows `Error 500 Internal`

this is the code from +page.server.js

```
import contentful from 'contentful';
import {
    CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY,
} from '$env/static/private';

export async function load({ params }) {
    const client = contentful.createClient({
        space: CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY
    });

    const { items } = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: 'news',
        'fields.slug': params.slug
    });

    return {
        article: items[0],
    };
}
```